# opengl offscreen rendering in linux is slow

Tags: linux, opengl, rendering, gpu, render

My opengl application runs at about 110 fps. The moment I add off-screen rendering, it slows down to 15 fps. I am using frame buffer objects and glReadPixels to render off-screen. I have searched on net and found that GPU memory to CPU memory data transfer is slow and vice versa is fast.
I have ATI Mobility Radeon™ X2300 with 128MB video memory.
 So my questions are
1) Is there is way to increase VRAM to CPU ram data transfer speed?
2) Are there any GPUs in market optimized for better read speed?

Comment: No and No. You can use a Pixel Buffer Object and re-structure your software so that you initiate the pixel transfer operation at the beginning of your frame and then use the memory after the GPU does some useful work. You cannot increase the speed of the memory transfer, only minimize the intrusiveness on the rest of the graphics pipeline by performing the transfer more intelligently. As with my answer to a similar question you had yesterday, this comes down to CPU / GPU synchronization; that is the bottleneck, not so much bus transfer rate.

Comment: What Andon has said + search for PBO pingpong and DMA asynchronous transferring.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the transfer speed but more the serialization between CPU and GPU. When you call glReadPixels in that way the CPU will stop and wait for the GPU to finish all rendering and this is quite inefficient as you noticed already.

The solution is to use PBOs. You can have N number of PBOs and on every frame you bind PBO X (where 0 <= X < N) and glReadPixels to that PBO. Before that you can map X and read the pixels of a past frame. N is not a magic number, for most implementations 3 frames delay is something usual. So N=3 is a good starting point.